# Can we solve the differential equation $f^{(4)}x=f(x)$ without using complex numbers?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation $f^{(4)}x=f(x)$, the solution is:$$f(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+c_3\sin x+c_4\cos x$$
The way I saw to solve it, was using complex numbers:
$$f(x)=e^{Ax}\\f^{(4)}(x)=A^4e^{Ax}\\A^4e^{Ax}=e^{Ax}\\A^4=1\\A=1,-1,i,-i$$
My question is, is there a way to solve this equation, and get to the same solution, without using complex numbers at all?

Comment: What's your motivation for not a wanting to use complex numbers?

Comment: Because looking at the solutions, I thought that for someone who doesn't know what complex numbers are, there must be a way to solve this without them.

Comment: The theory of linear ode depends greatly on the algebraic completeness of the complex field. Without using complex numbers, elementary linear ode will become merely a bag of tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a simple inspection we can see that $y=e^x$, $y=e^{-x}$, $y=\sin x$ and $y=\cos x$ are solutions of the equation. Since these are four linearly independent solutions of a $4$ order differential equation, a linear combination of them is the general solution.